# Get reference to UIBarButtonItem from UIButton?

Tags: ios, uibutton, uibarbuttonitem

I have created a `UIBarButtonItem` based on a `UIButton`. How can I get the reference of the `UIBarButtonItem` (!!!) in the event handler?

```
UIButton *brigthnessButton = [[UIButton alloc]
                                        initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 32, 32)];
[brigthnessButton setImage:newImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
 forState:UIControlStateSelected];
[brigthnessButton addTarget:self action:@selector(createShortcut:)
                  forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
shortCut = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:brigthnessButton];

- (void)createShortcut:(UIButton *)button {
    UIBarButtonItem *b = ??? 
}
```

Comment: Are you really sure you need an UIButton in a UIBarButtonItem? Users can also directly tap the UIBarButtonItem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your case

```
shortCut = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:brigthnessButton];
        [self.navigationItem setLeftBarButtonItem:shortCut];//if Left button

- (void)createShortcut:(UIButton *)button {

    UIBarbuttonItem *b = self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem;
}
```